# Kill excel process without saving

Tags: java, excel, kill

I have this code that kills any running Excel process correcly.

```
 public static void killExcel(){
     while (isProcessRuning("EXCEL.EXE")){
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM EXCEL.EXE");
     }
}

 public static boolean isProcessRuning(String serviceName) throws Exception {
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String line;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          if (line.contains(serviceName)) {
           return true;
          }
         }    
         return false;
    }
```

My problem is if the Excel file prompt the saving question, I got an infinit loop.

Comment: Please don't destroy the user's spreadsheets.

Comment: @SLaks, my Java application interact with a vba script on a server, no users involved, and I just want to be sure that all vba errors and Excel are closed befor proceeding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running `taskkill` with the /f option to forceably kill ? See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm) for more details.

It may be more appropriate to use the default option to allow Excel to quit nicely if it can. If it doesn't exit then revert to the forceable variant. Processes will normally exit if requested. If it's not, it's likely for a good reason.

Comment: I used "taskkill /f /t /IM excel.exe". It seems that the options's "/f /t" have to come befor "/IM" in order to work

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have an infinite loop is because it is in a while loop, you should put it in an if statement.  This way, it won't loop.  If all else fails then use /f.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void killExcel() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /t /IM EXCEL.EXE");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```